# Importing class imports argparse options as well

Tags: python, args

I have a script x_1.py, in which I defined a class Class_X.

Another script I am using is x_2.py, in which I have the following line:

```
from x_1 import Class_X
```

Both scripts x_1.py and x_2.py have different argsparse options. When I call  `python x_1.py --h`, I get the correct argument options for x_1.py. When I call `python x_2.py --h`, I receive the argument options of x_1.py, instead of those for x_2.

Any idea how to fix this...?

Comment: Is your argparser in a function or just sitting out in the open? Cause I would say a function would fix this...

Comment: That's a bit problematic. I'm using `argsparse`. If I put the parser in a function, it's arguments won't be recognized globally

Comment: At the very least, the call to `parse_args` should be in a `if __name__ == '__main__'` block, to ensure it is only called when you run `x_1.py` as a script, and not simply imported.

Comment: @Cheshie what do you mean "the arguments won't be recognized globally"?

Comment: @Cheshie Such functions typically return the value return by `parse_args`.

Comment: Just use `sys.argv`. Then its global

Comment: Oh, you mean the output won't be global. Just have a function that outputs the parsed args. Then assign the output of that function to global vars

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most likely (unless you are doing something really odd), you want to add a guard to `x_1.py` to protect code that isn't meant to be run if the script is imported instead.

```
def some_function():
   pass

p = argparse.ArgumentParser()
p.add_argument(...)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    args = p.parse_args()
    # do some other stuff
```

Now, if you import `x_1` into another module, only `some_function` and `p` will be defined; `p.parse_args` will not be called, and `p` itself will only be used if `x_2` decides to use it. If `p` is of no interest to other modules, its definition and configuration can be moved into the `if` statement as well.